# (maximal) antichains with respect to two different partial orders on the same set

Tags: posets, existence-theorems

In my recent work I stumbled across a problem of this type:

G with two partial oders $\leq$ and $\preceq$ on every set, i.e. for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ and $(A_n, \leq) $ and $(A_n, \preceq)$ are partially ordered sets (partial orders do not depend on $n$).

The question now is whether there exist for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ non-trivial sets $B \in \mathcal{P}(A_n)$ which are maximal antichains with respect to $(A_n,\leq)$ and $(A_n,\preceq)$? If so, how many?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Maximal antichains with respect to which order? What is $A$? It seems that the $A_n$'s play absolutely no role here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I edited the question to make things clearer and correct.

Comment: I honestly have no idea about why this sequence is even relevant to the question. You're now asking about a local statement that has nothing to do with other sets in your sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost a trivial counterexample:

Let $A_n$ be $\{0,\dots,n+2\}$ with one order being the usual $\leq$, that is a linear order, and another being $=$, that is the discrete order.

Note that all the $A_n$ have at least two elements. But the only sets which are antichains in *any* $A_n$ are singletons, which are never maximal with respect to $=$.